# how to web scrape data from graph

Tags: python, web-scraping

hi I would like to web scrape data from this internet page especially the graph of historical data ([Here](https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Historique/19801) and [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vl8Y6.jpg))

Maybe someone can help me how to proceed ? and more than that how can we do where and how to find the data.

Answer (score 1):

The data for the graph is stored inside the HTML document in Json form. To parse it you can use next example:

```py
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.quantalys.com/Fonds/Historique/19801"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
data = soup.select_one("[data-chartconfig]")["value"]
data = json.loads(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(data["dataProvider"])
df.columns = ["Date"] + [
    t["balloonText"].split(":", maxsplit=1)[-1].strip() for t in data["graphs"]
]
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
         Date  Amundi Euro High Yield Bond A EUR AD  Oblig. Europe Ht Rendt  ICE BofA European Currency High Yield Index
0  2020-06-19                                100.00                  100.00                                       100.00
1  2020-06-20                                100.00                  100.00                                       100.00
2  2020-06-21                                100.00                  100.00                                       100.00
3  2020-06-22                                 99.07                   99.78                                        99.80
4  2020-06-23                                 99.07                   99.85                                        99.85
```

Comment: How did you find this page ? I mean: soup.select_one("[data-chartconfig]")["value"]

Comment: @Jacques I've searched the HTML source for values which are in the graph.

Comment: How do you search the html source for values ? Because I tried « inspect the web page » but cannot found the data.

Comment: @Jacques Press `Ctrl + U` in Firefox/Chrome to show the source code and search for the values.

Comment: I am sorry but I tried to find the data but can't...Moreover there is a button to select the time frame (I choose 'Tout l'historique' - 'all period') then how to get all the period data ?

Comment: and where can I learn about this ?